# How can I extract voice files from the Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Charles Dance voices Emhyr Var Emreis in Witcher 3. He also plays Tywin Lannister in game of thrones

He has a good voice for reading bedtime stories. I like listening to audio before bed to help me fall asleep. Listen to this:

I'd like to put his voice in a sound file or a few sound files on my iPad Air 2, especially when he is not yelling to put in my playlist of bedtime sound files. Is there any easy way to get the sound and not take the loud volume ones?

**What do I do?** So say I buy the game then what? Some problems are - can stream the game on my computer but there will still be music in the background so that is a problem

I know very little about computers.

Comment: Witcher 3 from Projekt Red (GOG version) has some of the audio/video files as extras in readable formats... maybe you could look into that.